# Scratch Org: Source Push Error: reached maximum number of custom objects

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

I am trying to push a lot of source from a Dev Org into a Scratch Org using:

```
sfdx force:source:push
```

It gets to:

```
SOURCE PROGRESS | ...... 287/348 Components
```

And then I am getting a load of problems/errors, but the first 9 are quite odd:

> reached maximum number of custom objects

There are **27** folders in the `objects` folder in the source.

I created the Scratch Org using:

```
sfdx force:org:create --definitionfile .\config\project-scratch-def.json --targetusername my-scratch-org1
```

I just used the default `project-scratch-def.json`

```
{
  "orgName": "Demo company",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "securitySettings": {
      "passwordPolicies": {
        "enableSetPasswordInApi": true
      }
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    }
  }
}
```

Since then, I've deleted the scratch org, and I have tried to create more suitable org Shape using:

```
sfdx force:org:shape:create --loglevel TRACE
```

And I've updated the `project-scratch-def.json` to:

```
{
  "orgName": "My Scratch Org 2",
  "sourceOrg": "00D4K0000038xzt"
}
```

but when I run this command:

```
sfdx force:org:create --definitionfile .\config\project-scratch-def.json --targetusername my-scratch-org2
```

I get this error:

> ERROR running force:org:create:  No such column 'SourceOrg' on sobject of type ScratchOrgInfo

And when I run:

> sfdx force:org:shape:list

I get a lot of:

> ERROR:  ERROR: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND .....
> ERROR:  ERROR: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND .....
> ERROR:  ERROR: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND .....
> ERROR:  ERROR: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND .....
> ERROR:  ERROR: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND .....
> ERROR:  ERROR: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND .....

Then it hangs for a long time before saying:

> ERROR running force:org:shape:list:  Error authenticating with the refresh token due to: authentication failure

1. What is stopping the scratch org from being created from the shape?
2. Why am I getting all those errors when I list off the shapes?

Comment: How many objects do you have in the org? That error seems weird?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - 27 i think. I've updated the question.

Comment: Have you enabled dev hub and also whitelisted the dev hub from which you want to generate the org shapes?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - yes, `Dev Hub` is enabled, and `Enable Org Shape for Scratch Orgs (Beta)` is `On` in the source org, and the `Dev Hub` is white listed.

Comment: Also make sure you have the perms provided listed here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_permissions.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the edition as `Partner Developer` if you are an ISV as documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/isv_partner_scratch_org_editions.htm)

Also to get the exact shape of the org as similar to the one you have tried using the winter 21 org [shape](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_enable_org_shape.htm) feature. This will auto-build the features you need to enable and also add settings and licenses.

One key thing to note if you are using the Org Shape feature is to make sure you have enabled and assigned permission sets documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_permissions.htm)

- [Salesforce DX Developer Guide: Org Shape Permissions (Beta)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_permissions.htm)

Comment: Going back to the original `project-scratch-def.json` and changing the `edition` to `Partner Developer` got rid of the `reached maximum number of custom objects` error

Comment: Ok is your source org ID and the Dev Hub both same? If not one needs to whitelist 15 digit ID

Comment: My `Dev Hub` is our Production Org, and the Source Org is a separate `Partner Developer` org

Answer (score 3):

Scratch Orgs only support the minimum number of custom objects (50) by default. You can add more by using `"features":["AddCustomObjects:X"]`, where X is value from 1-30. See the [Features](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) section of the documentation. Note that Scratch Orgs are not meant to be an entire reproduction of your production org, which may have hundreds of custom objects (e.g. Unlimited Edition). You will need to break up your metadata into multiple packages. You may also try an [Org Shape](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_scratch_orgs_shape.htm) to mimic the licenses and limits of your production org, although it is unclear if this would match the CustomObject limits as well.